# Unable to create composer package - InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, exception, composer-php, packagist

I have been trying to create a simple composer package. But I'm stuck with the following issue. Dont know how to resolve this.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
Could not find package sarav/sample-package at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

Package Url : https://packagist.org/packages/sarav/sample-package

I ran the following composer command

```
composer require sarav/sample-package
```

My composer contents

```
{
    "name": "sarav/sample-package",
    "description": "Sample package",
    "type": "Library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
       {
          "name": "Sarav",
          "email": "me@sarav.co"
       }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
   "autoload": {
       "psr-0": {
          "Sarav": "src/"
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package config looks good to me, but your Git repo doesn't have any tagged versions.

Use `git tag v1.0.0` or whatever version is appropriate, then `git push origin --tags` to update on GitHub.

Alternatively, you can go without tagged versions by specifying the master branch when you *require* the package, like so:

`composer require sarav/sample-package dev-master`

You can require any branch in this manner, but the `dev-` prefix is mandatory.

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for help. It worked. Now I have created a new package for laravel. While I require it via composer I get an error. Can you help it? Here is the link https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4407

Comment: I've replied on your GitHub issue :)